# cache memory size limitations

Tags: caching, memory

I knew that cache memory stores the frequently used data to speed up process execution instead fetching them from main memory -which is slower- every time , and it's size always small in comparison with main memory because it's expensive technology and because always the real data are being processed at a time is very smaller than the whole data process held by main memory .

But is there any limitations or constrains regarding cache memory size at a some CPU speed or a some main memory size ? theoretically , if we increased the cache memory much .. will that affect in an opposite way ? or just it will be a waste increase ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the performance gain become less and less significant after 64KB of cache size.
Here is graph from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) showing that regardless of the scheme of set-associativity the miss-rate decrease only slightly as the cache size increases pass 64KB [image: Miss rate versus cache size on the Integer portion of the SPEC CPU2000]

Answer (score 0):

Caches are small because the silicon used to build them is quite expensive and, expecially on CISC-type CPUs, there might not be enough space on the chip to hold them. Also making chips bigger has it cost and there's the possibility that it won't fit in its socket, which adds many more issues. It's not that simple ;)

**EDIT:**
Well, I haven't got any papers about this, but I'll explain my opinion anyway with a simple question: if a programs needs x bytes of memory, what would be the difference if the cache's size is 10 * x bytes or 100 * x? Once all the data is loaded in the cache (which doesn't depend on its size at all), the difference is all in the cache's access speed. And given [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), it's not necessary having everything on cache.
Also, having big chaches requires having better algorithm for searching requested data in it. For example accessing data in a [fully associative caches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Associativity) will become slower than accessing the main memory as the cache size increases (which implies there are more and more places to look for the data). Considering multitasking system, though, introduces other issues which I don't actually know much of.

To conclude, the performance gain caused by increasing caches' size becomes slighter as it approaches the usual amount of data used by the whole software running on a given machine.

Comment: Thanks for your response , I agree with you and that why I said "theoretically" , if we eliminated cost , manufacturing and compatibility factors ... would it theoretically give us a counterproductive behavior ? or it'll be just a wast increase ?

In some articles I saw that the relationship between cache memory size and a main memory size is more likely 1 to 1000 and any increase in cache size will leads to nearly no change in performance ..... is there any graphs , formulas or articles about this ?